# Android value to Sqlite table

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Hi I am developing and android app in which a login and signup page is there when user enters the username and password a passcode will be sent to the mobile number and after that he will enter to registation page where he needs to enter username,password and passcode for verification.. So I need is a random value has to be given to the table like'1' or something for successful registration..else '0' like that.. can anyone help..

Register Activity

```
public class RegisterActivity extends Activity {


    LoginDataBaseAdapter loginDataBaseAdapter;
    Button btnReg;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.register_xm);


        loginDataBaseAdapter=new LoginDataBaseAdapter(this);
        loginDataBaseAdapter=loginDataBaseAdapter.open();



        btnReg = (Button) findViewById (R.id.buttonRegister);

        final  EditText editTextUserName=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextUserNameToLogin);
        final  EditText editTextPassword=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextPasswordToLogin);
        final  EditText editTextMobileNumber = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);



        btnReg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub


                String userName=editTextUserName.getText().toString();
                String password=editTextPassword.getText().toString();
                String mobileNumber = editTextMobileNumber.getText().toString();

                // fetch the Password form database for respective user name
                String storedPassword=loginDataBaseAdapter.getSinlgeEntry(userName);



                String sd = getIntent().getStringExtra("number"); 
                String name = editTextUserName.getText().toString();



                // check if the Stored password matches with  Password entered by user
                if(password.equals(storedPassword) && (mobileNumber.equals(sd))) 
                {
                    Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "Congrats: Registration Successfull", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


                    Intent in = new Intent(RegisterActivity.this,HomePageActivity.class);
                    startActivity(in);



                }
                else
                {
                    Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "User Name, Passcode or Password does not match", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }


            }
        });


    }







@Override
protected void onDestroy() 
     {
    super.onDestroy();
    // Close The Database
    loginDataBaseAdapter.close();

      }
    }
```

signup Activity

```
public class SignUpActivity extends Activity

{

    EditText editTextUserName,editTextPassword,editTextConfirmPassword, editMobileNumber;
    Button btnCreateAccount;



    // Progress Dialog
        private ProgressDialog pDialog;

        JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();




    Random r = new Random();
    int number =r.nextInt(9999 - 1000) + 1000;



    LoginDataBaseAdapter loginDataBaseAdapter;


private static String url_create_data = "http://iascpl.com/app/create_data1.php";

    // JSON Node names
    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.signup_xm);



        // get Instance  of Database Adapter
                loginDataBaseAdapter=new LoginDataBaseAdapter(this);
                loginDataBaseAdapter=loginDataBaseAdapter.open();

                // Get References of Views


                editTextUserName=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextUserName);
                editTextPassword=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextPassword);
                editTextConfirmPassword=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextConfirmPassword);
                editMobileNumber = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.mobileNumber);




                btnCreateAccount=(Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonCreateAccount);

                btnCreateAccount.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                        String name=editTextUserName.getText().toString();
                        String password=editTextPassword.getText().toString();
                        String confirmPassword=editTextConfirmPassword.getText().toString();

                        String phoneNo = editMobileNumber.getText().toString();
                        String sms = Integer.toString(number);


                        //Intent intent = new Intent(SignUpActivity.this, RegisterActivity.class);

                        //intent.putExtra("number", sms + "");
                        //startActivity(intent);



                        //new CreateNewProduct().execute();


                        StringTokenizer st=new StringTokenizer(phoneNo,",");
                        while (st.hasMoreElements())

                        {

                            String tempMobileNumber = (String)st.nextElement();
                            if(tempMobileNumber.length()>0 && sms.trim().length()>0) 
                            {
                                sendSMS(tempMobileNumber, sms);

                            }


                            else 

                            {

                                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), 
                                        "Please enter both phone number and message.", 
                                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }





                        }








                        // check if any of the fields are vacant
                        if(name.equals("")||password.equals("")||confirmPassword.equals(""))
                        {
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Field Vaccant", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                return;
                        }
                        // check if both password matches
                        if(!password.equals(confirmPassword))
                        {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Password does not match", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            return;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            // Save the Data in Database
                           loginDataBaseAdapter.insertEntry(name, password);
                          Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Passcode is sent to the mobile number you provided. ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();     


                            new CreateNewProduct().execute();

                           // Intent intent = new Intent(SignUpActivity.this, RegisterActivity.class);

                          //  intent.putExtra("number", sms + "");
                           // startActivity(intent);



                        }







                    }
                });

    }









    private void sendSMS(String phoneNumber, String message)
    {
        String SENT = "SMS_SENT";
        String DELIVERED = "SMS_DELIVERED";

        PendingIntent sentPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,
            new Intent(SENT), 0);

        PendingIntent deliveredPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,
            new Intent(DELIVERED), 0);

      //---when the SMS has been sent---
        registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver(){
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
                switch (getResultCode())
                {
                    case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS sent", 
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                    case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_GENERIC_FAILURE:
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Generic failure", 
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                    case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NO_SERVICE:
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No service", 
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                    case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NULL_PDU:
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Null PDU", 
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                    case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_RADIO_OFF:
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Radio off", 
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                }
            }
        },new IntentFilter(SENT));

        //---when the SMS has been delivered---
        registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver(){
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
                switch (getResultCode())
                {
                    case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS delivered", 
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                    case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS not delivered", 
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;                        
                }
            }
        }, new IntentFilter(DELIVERED));        

        SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
        sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, sentPI, deliveredPI);       


    }













    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onDestroy();

        loginDataBaseAdapter.close();
    }



    /**
     * Background Async Task to Create new product
     * */
    class CreateNewProduct extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        /**
         * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
         * */
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(SignUpActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Creating a new account..");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        /**
         * Creating product
         * */
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {





            String name = editTextUserName.getText().toString();
            String password = editTextPassword.getText().toString();
            String mobile = editMobileNumber.getText().toString();
            String sms = Integer.toString(number);

            // Building Parameters
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", name));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("mobile", mobile));

            // getting JSON Object
            // Note that create product url accepts POST method
            JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_create_data,
                    "POST", params);

            // check log cat fro response
            Log.d("Create Response", json.toString());

            // check for success tag
            try {
                int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

                if (success == 1) {
                    // successfully created product




                    Intent i = new Intent(SignUpActivity.this, RegisterActivity.class);

                    i.putExtra("number", sms + "");
                    startActivity(i);

                    //closing this screen
                    //finish();
                } else {
                    // failed to create product
                    return "false";



                }



            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
         * **/
        /*protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog once done
            pDialog.dismiss();
        }*/


        protected void onPostExecute(String result)

        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPostExecute(result);
                        if (result == "false")
            Toast.makeText(SignUpActivity.this, "User Name already exists. Please choose another user name ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        pDialog.dismiss();

        }


    }





}
```

Comment: You can generate any random number while entering the username and password. And after generating random number save that number anywhere in your application and check with the database whether that number exists or not. If it exists then allow to login otherwise not.

Comment: what you actually want's to do is: generate a random number to send user as pass code?

Answer (score 0):

You can generate different random values like this.

```
System.currentTimeMillis(); //It return long value of current time. This value always will be unique.
```